# Elements get visually bigger after build on iPhone Xs Max (Expo/React Native)

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, expo, testflight

I just downloaded a build of my app through TestFlight to my iPhone Xs Max, and the size of all my elements (both views and text elements) changes significantly from when I’m running it via the Expo app on the same phone. Take a look at the screenshot:

[Left: Downloaded build, Right: Running in Expo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztgx5.jpg)

The app on the left is the downloaded build, and the right is running it via the Expo app. I want to make sure that what I’m seeing as I’m writing the code is the same what gets deployed. Any idea why the dimensions are changing?

(I also noticed there's some weird artifacts, almost like the app is rendering the elements at the proper size, then scaling each element up so it looks a little pixelated.)

Comment: You may have Dynamic Size enabled in your phone, check in your settings

Go to Settings > General > Accessibility > Larger Text.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. Dynamic size is turned off. :/

Answer (score 0):

Need to confirm that , it is develop in scalemode or in autolayout. If it is implement by autolayout then it should display proper in all device. if is was implement in scalemode then, need to change it to autolayout to check expected UI in all device.